# No rotations after programmatically setting rootViewController in iOS 8

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8

After programmatically setting `self.window.rootViewController` in my controller, none of the orientation change callbacks (old or new) are called for the rest of the time the app is running under iOS 8. Is there a different way you are supposed to do that in iOS 8? or is this a bug and if so does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Which callbacks namely? I can confirm iOS still calls `viewWillLayoutSubviews` on my custom root view controller, when going to rotate the screen. No change from iOS 7.1 in that.

Comment: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation, and the iOS 8 equivalents don't get called. This only happens when a viewController is presented modally over another, and *then* I make it the rootViewController since I don't need the one underneath it any more. If I just instantiate it from the storyboard and set it to be the rootViewController everything works fine though, I just ended up doing that and cutting out the modal presentation.